# Set the max value in colormap when using scale_color_viridis

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

Here is the code:

```
pic = ggplot(df_2, 
aes(x = df_2$X, xend = df_2$X + df_2$dx, y = df_2$Y, yend = df_2$Y + df_2$dy, color =  df_2$speedkt)) +
labs(title ="Surface Currents", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", colour="Speed (kts)") +    
geom_segment(alpha = 0.7, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1,"cm"))) + coord_fixed() +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)) +
viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = "B", direction = -1)
```

You can see the color gradient follows the value of `df_2$speedkt` . The maximum value of `df_2$speedkt` is around 2.6.

So, the maximum value of the colormap in the legend is around 2.8.

But I wish to change the maximum value of the colormap to 4.0.

What I can do?

[image: Colormap in Legend Highlighted]

Comment: Note that `ggplot2` has these scales build in nowadays, `scale_color_viridis_c` in this case.

Comment: FYI, no need to use `df_2$` inside `ggplot` call. You can just use bare column names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your main question, you should be able to pass `limits = c(0, 4)` as an argument to `viridis::scale_color_viridis()`, i.e.

```
viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = "B", direction = -1, limits = c(0, 4))
```

A couple of other points:

- Newer versions of `ggplot2` have viridis scales built in, so you should be able to use:

```
scale_color_viridis_c(option = "B", direction = -1, limits = c(0, 4))
```

- In general, it's better not to use `df$col` in `aes()`, just use the column name, e.g.

```
ggplot(df_2, aes(x = X, xend = X + dx, y = Y))
```

ggplot will look up the column names within the dataframe.

Comment: can u insert the output ?

Comment: @saisaran: The question doesn't provide an easy way to reproduce the data/plot, so I can't show how it changes the plot.